# Where do I connect the green wire?

Tags: wire

I have 2 headset and i want to fix them together. The other headset has green, red, blue and copper color. The other one just blue, red and copper only.

Comment: just be careful not to clip the red wire!

Comment: *i want to fix them together.* I suggest to use **glue**. Also this has nothing to do with "wirebonding" as that term refers to how integrated circuits (chips) are connected to their package.

Comment: WHAT? headphone wire colours are not consistent with each other? This changes everything.

Comment: Does one of them have a microphone built in?

Answer (score 1):

Headphones have two speaker each with two wires. Normally two of the wires are connected together as a common 'ground' The stereo signal then come in over the other two wires.

On one of your headphones that has been done. On the other it still is four separate wires. You will need an Ohm meter to find out which wire pairs belong to which speaker. Then you can connect two wires together to make a common ground.

Alternative to an Ohm meter is a 1.5Volt battery. You rapidly connect and dis-connect it to two wires and listen which of the speakers give sound. If you have two wires from different speakers you will get no sound.

The same trick can be used on the headphone with three wires. If you hear sound from one speaker you have a plus and a ground. If you hear sound from *both* speakers you have two plus wires.

Ideally you want to connect the speakers 'in phase'. That is: the plus goes to the plug and the minus wires are connected together and go to ground. Per definition, if you connect a speaker to a battery and the cone goes forward you have the correct polarity (that is: the wire which is connected to the + of the battery is the plus wire of the speaker.) But this works only if you can see the speaker cone.

By the way: I have never heard the difference with a headphone if the speakers where in phase or not. It is more important with room speakers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIXHjl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>